# How to call action method from jQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, datatable, datatables, asp.net-ajax

I need to call action method for jQuery datatable which is going to return partial view.

Let me explain

1. I have a table which is having list of requests. when user click particular request it should show the details description then they will add/modify/delete.
2. Totally i have 2 partial view one is list of request another one detail description

View Code:

```
 <tbody>
    @foreach (var gt in Model.ChangeReq)
    {
       <tr>
          <td>@gt.reqId </td>                   
          <td>@gt.title </td>
          <td>@gt.status </td>
          <td>@gt.department </td>
          <td>Select </td>
       </tr>
    }
 </tbody>
```

Javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#chmReq').dataTable({
        "pageLength": 6,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "searching": true,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("Search", "FilterCondition")',
           "aoColumns": [
                    {
                        "sName": "changeId",
                        "bSearchable": false,
                        "bSortable": false,
                        "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                         return '<a href=\"Details/' +
                         oObj.aData[0] + '\">View</a>';
                        }
                    },
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,

                ]
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult FilterCondition(string reqId)
{            
    _model.ChangeReq = _repository.GetRequestDetails(reqId);           
    return PartialView("_FilterChangeRequest",_model);
}
```

Question:
Is there any other way to call action method?
i want use Datatable because i need pagination,searching,sorting etc...

Comment: which action method you want to call

Comment: Hi jay, thanks. i need to call FilterCondition action method.